# ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT IpInfo Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, web, ip

tengo un problema. Estoy intentando utilizar ipinfo para obtener el JSON con la información del cliente que va a usar mi web. El problema es que al usar esta api con un adblock (yo uso uBlock Origin) no puedo obtener dicha información y me da este error:

[image: Error consola]

El código que utilizo es el siguiente

```
<input type="hidden" id="DatosClientes"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
   async function getIpClient() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://ipinfo.io/json');
            document.getElementById("DatosClientes").value =  JSON.stringify(response);
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }

    getIpClient();

</script>
```